# Using NSPredicate with Cloud Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of `songs` by an Arabic artist. I'm trying filter the songs using my searchBar.

I have used NSPredicate as it's quite hard to navigate through using arabic characters.

Apple | تفاح

Filtering code:

```
let searchText = "تفاح"
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchText)
let docRef = db.collection("songs").order(by: "songTitle").filter(using: resultPredicate)
```

Getting:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid query. Operator type 99 is not supported.'